# PHP matches against 2 strings

Tags: php, string, match

I have a 2 strings to compare.

```
$base_string =  "job, jobs, hiring, for hire, hire";
$user_string = "virtual assistant jobs";

if($user_string matches $base_string){
    return true; //true for jobs word
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Base from the pseudocode above, can you help me how to code the above logic?

Comment: You should use strpos() or in_array() if you use arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php OR http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: What do you actually need to compare? Like words or the complete string?

Comment: So, you want to match each term in `$user_string` against each term in `$base_string`? If so, I think you'll be better off [exploding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them into arrays first then looking for where they [intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$base_string =  "job, jobs, hiring, for hire, hire";
$user_string = "virtual assistant jobs";

$array_match = explode(",",$base_string);
$array_search = explode(" ",$user_string);

if(sizeof(array_intersect($array_match,$array_search)) > 0){
    return true; //true for jobs word
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly, if that's what's required ;)

Comment: Should use `preg_split` for optional spaces around commas, or include them if they're always there no matter what. Also your last line can be `return count(array_intersect($array_match, $array_search)) > 0);`.

Comment: Remove the whitespaces:
$array_match = array_map('trim', explode(",",$base_string));

Comment: Thank you @dieter. This works. Just have to add a space in explode delimeter parameter to work the matching. 
`$array_match = explode(", ",$base_string);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
<?php

$base_string =  "job, jobs, hiring, for hire, hire";
$user_string = "virtual assistant jobs";

$user_string = explode(" ", $user_string); //store the search string in a array to loop through with strpos

foreach ($user_string as $string_value){

  $string = $string_value;
  if (strpos($base_string, $string) !== false) {
        echo 'true';
  } else {
        echo 'false';
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this wont work for $user_string with 'in my place' word. In still will fall into it and return true result.